# Recurrence for C(N+1) - C(N) of mergesort

Tags: time-complexity, mergesort

I am reading "An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms" by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne. In this book, Exercise 1.4 asks to develop a recurrence for $C_{N+1} - C_{N}$ and use it to prove that

$$C_N = \sum_{1\leq k < N}{(\lfloor\lg{k}\rfloor + 2)}$$

where $C_{N}$ is the number of compares of mergesort.

Any idea of how to prove it?

---

To make this question self-contained, I added some context: Mergesort uses $C_N = N\lg{N} + O(N)$ compares to sort an array of $N$ elements. And when $N = 2^n$, $C_N$ is $N\lg{N}$.

### What I tried

Consider the case when $N = 2^n$, $C_{N+1} - C_N = (N+1)\lg{(N+1)} - N\lg{N} = N\lg{((N+1)/N)} + \lg{(N+1)}$.

If $N \to \infty$, $C_{N+1} - C_N = \lg{e} + \lg{(N+1)}$.

To sum up from $C_N - C_{(N-1)}$ to $C_2 - C_1$, we have

$$C_N - C_1 \leq \sum_{1\leq k \leq N}{(\lg{k} + \lg{e})} 
< \sum_{1\leq k \leq N}{(\lg{k} + 2)}$$.

Given the fact that $C_1 = 0$, we have $C_N < \sum_{1\leq k \leq N}{(\lg{k} + 2)}$.

The result's form is similar to the intended one, but I don't know how to get the exact bound of $C_N$.

Comment: 1. Most readers here will not have a copy of that book handy. To help them help you, consider adding enough context to make your question self-contained.
2. What have you tried?

Comment: @Kai Thanks. I have added some context and what I have tried.